WebSphere lister did not go down when schema has been changed in the table. Messages were keep on Failing
I have added the maxretrieslimit =3 then it started stopping the listener when message was not processed but in one case the listener is not going down when message is not processed even. That case is : I have updated the database table with 10 extra columns for table then deployed those changes on server. Since then messages are failing but listener did not go down. That is really strange for me. But I could not able to find the root cause but when I restarted jvm then messages were started processed. But still I do not have clue why listener did not go down in this scenario. Could you please help me on this ? I really want to know the reason.
When messages are not processed then Listener should go down after 3 retries. But that did not happen when i have added extra columns in the table.
I am expecting to go down the listener when messages are not processed.
